# Webapp and Wordpress accessible both from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

I've built a webapp and now I need to pair it with a Wordpress blog.
The SEO guy wants the blog to be accessible straight from the root domain and I'm not sure that's possible.

What I would need to set up is:

```
https://webapp.com/ -> go to the webapp homepage  
https://webapp.com/products/wine -> go to the webapp product page for wine  
https://webapp.com/best_wines -> go to the wordpress page "best_wines"
```

What the SEO guy simply wants is having WP pages that are shown as they belong to the same domain.

The webapp, written upon Rails, is accessible from Nginx that proxies the requests to Puma.
The webapp and Wordpress live in two different machines (two Digital Ocean droplets to be more specific).

I thought about adding a redirect in Nginx for every WP page that need to be shown and although I highly dislike it, it's a solution and maybe it's the only viable one.
The wp admin will not be redirect and it will reside at https://webapp.com/blog/wp-admin

Does a solution exist for this kind of problem?

Comment: The `nginx` redirect solution seems a plausible solution to me, also. Another option would be to leverage the redirection to the Wordpress pages in the Rails app routes/controllers (but it would bring unnecessary load to the app server)

Comment: Thanks @pedrosfdcarneiro . I didn't think about the `routes` solution although having nginx hard-coded paths still seems a better solution.